# How to get unique id of WiFi in android?

Tags: android

I can get a name of WiFi using the code String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID(),
but you know many WiFi have the same name such as "MyWiFi", I hope to get unique id of a WiFi, how can I do? Thanks!

Tips:
I hope to upload my file in my app only when I connect to my home WiFi named "MyWiFi", but in other place, there are many WiFi named "MyWiFi".

```
  if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Wifi is connected                
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

            Toast.makeText(context, "OK " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && ! networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is disconnected: "+String.valueOf(networkInfo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use below network id.

```
getNetworkId()
```

used to identify the network when performing operations on the supplicant.

UPDATE YOUR CODE

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
     String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
     int networkid = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
     Toast.makeText(context, "OK " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Toast.makeText(context, "Network ID  " + networkid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result of Network ID  is 0 in my android 2.3.6 phone, is it correct?

Comment: This method return (each configured network has a unique small integer ID)
default return value is -1, so this might be right try to run on other device and in other wifi network. Also try with another wifi network and see what you get in that network.

Comment: Is it possible that  Network ID also return 0 if I connect other WiFi  named "MyWiFi" ? Thanks!

Comment: No, I think not, But I not tested the same, For every different network there is diffrent network ID

Comment: And more can I use getBSSID() to judge a WiFi uniquely? Thanks!

Comment: BSSID is  basic service set identifier (BSSID) of the current access point,
Because it depends on access point suppose if there is two wifi in on same access point than BSSID is not unique.
Please refer this link  http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/network-director1.5/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html

Answer (score 0):

> The unique id of any wifi added is NETWORK_ID[The ID number that the supplicant uses to identify this network configuration entry.].

**how do i get network id?**

if you have  WifiConfiguration object you get get its network id

For more detial on apis look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BSSID as a unique identifier
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Basic_service_set_identification_.28BSSID.29

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)     this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name is  " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String networkid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network ID  " + networkid,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```