# Limit WiFi connections listed as available on Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have an application where I need connect to a network provided by a device developed by me. The device provides a WiFi network that has a fixed prefix (e.g. "AAB").

Is it possible to limit the available WiFi networks to networks that contains my prefix? This way, I can only choose one of them to connect.

Currently, I just create an `Intent` for `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK`, which shows me all available network:

```
startActivity( new Intent( WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231677/how-to-get-unique-id-of-wifi-in-android), you can search for all the available WiFi connections and filter them on basis of their IDs, or in your case, check if they start with the prefix or not.

Referencing the code from post above for quick overview:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
int networkid = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
Toast.makeText(context, "OK " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(context, "Network ID  " + networkid,             
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can also use the [BSSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Basic_service_set_identification_.28BSSID.29) as a unique identifier

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the interface of the `startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));` or I need to implement on similar layout myself?

Comment: You'll have to create a custom dialog with a list of compatible WiFi's according to you needs. Also, please up-vote/accept the answer if you found it useful :D